# Using Math.Abs on nullable decimal property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have a object of type.

```
class A
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public decimal? Num {get;set;}
}
```

Then I have `List<A> objList` data populated from db .
I need to make Num as positive number , so
I tried to do the following.

```
objList = objList.ForEach(x=>x.Num = Math.Abs(x.Num));
```

Since the Num is nullable decimal , I am not able to use it in Linq. How Can I use it so that I can skip null values and convert -ve values to +ve one using Math.abs?

Comment: _How Can I use it so that I can skip null values_ - this isn't very clear but if you want to drop the values where `Num` is null you could do this - `objList = objList.Where(o => o.Num.HasValue).Select(o => new A { Id = o.Id, Num = Math.Abs(o.Num.Value) }).ToList();`

Comment: @stuartd I'm pretty sure "skip" means ignore rather than remove from the list.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: Yes you are right . Skip means ignore it

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I thought that made sense, but the values were assigned back to `objList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `List<T>.ForEach()` to mutate the list. Instead, I'd use a simple `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach (var item in objList.Where(item => item.Num != null))
{
    item.Num = Math.Abs(item.Num!.Value);
}
```

Note: If using nullable checking, you must use `!` to suppress a warning in `item.Num!.Value` because the compiler isn't smart enough to figure out that because of the `Where` it can't be null.

Also note that this approach avoids the redundant assignment of `null` to an already-null `Num` which occurs for the other solutions.

(See [Eric Lippert's post on foreach vs ForEach](https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) for some discussion on why you shouldn't use `List<T>.ForEach()` to mutate a list.)

Comment: Eric Lippert discussed why `ForEach` hasn't been added to LINQ. The only mention of `List<T>.ForEach` was that you're "_not supposed to mutate a list while you are iterating it_", but that's exactly what you are dong with the standard `foreach`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Pay attention to the part where Eric says `Doing this lets you rewrite this perfectly clear code:` ... `into this code:`. I agree with him that the code using `List<T>.ForEach()` is not as clear. *That* is what I want to draw attention to.

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach` is not LINQ, [it's an instance method on `List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach) which updates the list in place.

You could use a ternary expression to only apply `Math.Abs` when `Num` is not null:

```
objList.ForEach(x => x.Num = x.Num is decimal d ? Math.Abs(d) : null);
```

Comment: This wouldn't update anything though? and x.Num is still of type `decimal?` regardless of your null chuck so I'm pretty sure you'd still need to use x.Num.Value

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach` is not part of LINQ but rather a [method defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-6.0) on `List<T>` and it returns `void` (so you can't assign it's result to `objList` i.e. `objList = objList.ForEach` ).

You can use [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) with check for `x.Num` having value and use that value for `Math.Abs`:

```cs
objList.ForEach(x => x.Num = x.Num.HasValue ? Math.Abs(x.Num.Value) : null);
```